# Preventing Excel opening a file as read only that is locked for editing

Tags: microsoft-excel

If a file is locked for editing Excel allows the file to be opened as read only and saved as different file name.  I want to avoid this and stop the file from being opened at all if it is locked for editing by another user.

Comment: maybe you could create a marco that on file open tests if it is read only, and closes if yes. Save this into your personal.xlsm to have it always available.

Comment: That sounds like a possibility.  I'll investigate.  Thanks.